# Relation between shm_open and mmap?

Tags: linux, shared-memory, mmap, memory-mapped-files

I have read many `shm_open` docs. All of the [docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) are showing how it should be used with `mmap`. I didn't get why it should be used with `mmap`? What does `mmap` do extra from `shm_open`? The docs states:

> shm_open() is analogous to that of open().

If this is true, then why can't I read/write directly to the shared memory object, just like regular files with `open()`. If `shm_open` and `mmap` should always be used together, why they didn't just merge them into one API?

Comment: Well, I think `mmap` does to shm_opened object the same as it does to opened file - gives you an access to the 'file/object' through a continuous address space. You can use it, but you don't have to, and access the shm_open object through normal read/write function calls.